# Make a limit in a sub array of a MongoDB document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB collection that allows to store videos rankings, here is the schema:

```
var ChallengeVideoRankingSchema = new Schema({
    _challenge: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Challenge',
    },
    since: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['all', 'day', 'week', 'month']
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['won_duels', 'diamonds']
    },
    total: {
        type: Number
    },
    challengeVideos: [
        {
            rank: {
                type: Number
            },
            _challengeVideo: {
                type: ObjectId,
                ref: 'ChallengeVideo'
            }
        }
    ],
    creation_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
});
```

I would like to make a request with mongoose which allows me to retrieve some of the ChallengeVideo objects in one of the rankings to make a pagination. I would like for example to have in the field "challengeVideos", 20 objects representing the ranks 1-20, 21-40, 41-60, ... according to a given parameter.

Thank you in advance,

Bastien

Comment: You can general "page" an array by using [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) but if you want to sort an array at runtime you need to use an aggregation operation. If your general intent is to most commonly retrieve by "rank" then you should look at the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) modifier to `$push` and keep your array updated in the required order.

Comment: Maybe $skip and $limit will work for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Get last elements with slice

```
db.posts.find( {}, { comments: { $slice: -3 } } )
```

link https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/#return-an-array-with-its-last-3-elements